# Join table to itself without duplicating

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've got a transaction table like:

```
id |  incoming | value |      created_at
--------------------------------------------
1  |     t     | 1.88  | 2016-09-23 11:01:02
2  |     t     | 1.55  | 2016-09-23 11:02:02
3  |     t     | 0.73  | 2016-09-23 11:03:02
4  |     t     | 2.30  | 2016-09-23 11:04:02
5  |     t     | 0.82  | 2016-09-23 11:05:02
6  |     t     | 1.01  | 2016-09-23 11:06:02
7  |     t     | 2.33  | 2016-09-23 11:07:02
8  |     f     | 7.00  | 2016-09-23 11:08:02
9  |     f     | 1.20  | 2016-09-23 11:09:02
10 |     f     | 0.74  | 2016-09-23 11:10:02
11 |     f     | 1.53  | 2016-09-23 11:11:02
```

Am I able to get table like this with one query without any additional database function:

```
 true_value | false_value |      true_date       |     false_date
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1.88     |    7.00     | 2016-09-23 11:01:02  | 2016-09-23 11:08:02
   1.55     |    1.20     | 2016-09-23 11:02:02  | 2016-09-23 11:09:02
   0.73     |    0.74     | 2016-09-23 11:03:02  | 2016-09-23 11:10:02
   2.30     |    1.53     | 2016-09-23 11:04:02  | 2016-09-23 11:11:02
   0.82     |    NULL     | 2016-09-23 11:05:02  |         NULL
   1.01     |    NULL     | 2016-09-23 11:06:02  |         NULL
   2.33     |    NULL     | 2016-09-23 11:07:02  |         NULL
```

It's like join table to itself where `incoming = TRUE` to `incoming = FALSE`, but each `incoming = TRUE` row gets only one `incoming = FALSE` row without duplicates

Comment: Could you show the query?

Comment: @McNets I have no query, and this is my question. I just know what I want to get, but can't find the way

Comment: You specify you table data, and then you say "Am I able to get table like this with one query", and now you say you have no query... Show us your current query, and also specify the expected result!

Comment: how are you linking `1.88` to `7.00`? is it merely based on the order of the rows? doesn't sound right

Comment: @Stephen 1.88 value is a first `true` value, 7.00 is a first `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign row numbers to the true and false incoming records, ordered by the `id` column, and then join on those row numbers.  This would match up the true and false records in accordance with your expected output.  I use a common table expression here for readability and also to minimze the amount of code we need to do this.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, incoming, value, created_at,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY incoming ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM transaction
)
SELECT t1.value AS true_value,
       t2.value AS false_value,
       t1.created_at AS true_date,
       t2.created_at AS false_date
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn AND
       t2.incoming = 'f'
WHERE t1.incoming = 't'
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. Actually you show me the right way and i've already fix your query for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

The previous post is correct, although not quite complete as it is missing filter on the true/false. Here is a sample with two CTEs, one for true values and one for false values that is then combined.

```
with
  i as (select incoming, value, created_at, row_number() over (order by id asc) as RowNum from TRans where incoming = 't'),
  o as (select incoming, value, created_at, row_number() over (order by id asc) as RowNum from TRans where incoming = 'f')
select i.value as true_value, o.value as false_value, i.created_at as true_date, o.created_at as false_Date
  from i
  left outer join o on i.RowNum = o.RowNum
```

Comment: Also, a better solution would be to have a column with a transaction_id that could be used to join the corresponding incoming / outgoing rows, but I do not know if that is a possibility in your scenario.

Comment: Only works if there are more true values than false.

Comment: True, I assumed an outgoing transaction would only be sent as a response to an incoming transaction. If that is not the case then a full join instead of left outer join would solve that issue.

Comment: You don't need two separate CTE, a single one will suffice.